# Update Windows Store app for Windows 8 users only

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10

We have an app in the Windows 8 store. The app needs to be updated ASAP for Windows 10 to be preinstalled (OEM app). There will be a critical update later for Windows 8 users. Can I still updated the Windows 8 app separately without affecting the Windows 10 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to add packages for each platform. This way it's possible to update them seperately.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188601.aspx)

Comment: thank you so much! is it just me or is the windows help very poorly indexed by google and/or msdn search? i've searched many times but never found anything...

Comment: I think because of Microsoft's constant change of technologies makes their content hard to find. When searching for help should one search for c#, winrt, silverlight, uap, uwp, windows (7, 8, 8.1, 10), windows phone (7, 7.1, 7.5, 8, 8.1) or .net?

Comment: Also their search feature on dev.windows.com is horrible.